# passport.authenticate is not a function / User.findone is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

**I can't figure out for the life of me of what I am doing wrong.  I am very new to passport and js in general but any help would be appreciated! Everytime I try to run in, I get authenticate is not a function,  Then if I require passport in my htmlRoutes.js I get findOne is not a function.  Very confused
**

**This is my passport.js**

```
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const User = require("../routes/htmlRoutes");

passport.use(
new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: "email" }, function (
email,
password,
done
) {
User.findOne({ email: email }, function (err, user) {
  if (err) {
    return done(err);
  }
  if (!user) {
    return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect Email..." });
  }
  if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
    return done(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password..." });
  }
  return done(null, user);
});
})
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
done(err, user);
});
});

module.exports = passport;
```

**My Schema**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
first_name: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
last_name: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
email: {
type: String,
required: true,
unique: true,
},
password: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

**My htmlRoutes.js. In Here, if i change passport to require('passport'),  I lose the error for authenticate but it doesnt make any sense to me to do it like that**

```
const express = require("express");
const Router = express.Router();
const User = require("../models/User");
const passport = require("../config/passport");

Router.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.render("index");
});

Router.post(
"/login",
passport.authenticate("local", {
successRedirect: "/dashboard",
failureRedirect: "/login",
failureFlash: true,
})
);

Router.get("/dashboard", (req, res) => {
res.render("dashboard");
});

Router.post("/new/users", (req, res) => {
User.create({
first_name: req.body.first_name,
last_name: req.body.last_name,
email: req.body.email,
password: req.body.password,
}).then((data) => {
res.send(data);
});
});

module.exports = Router;
```

Comment: you can do `require('passport')` without a problem because it's in `node_modules` so you don't need a path. Just the name of the module.

Comment: What is the question? Can you supply error message? Or which part is failing?

Comment: Hey as of for the findOne issue, look you're not importing the collection from the UserSchema, but you're importing the `Router htmlRoutes.js`.

It must be something like this

`const User = require("../models/userSchema");` and this must solve the user.findOne() error.

Comment: You need to require the models and the not the routes that is where your mistake is use const User = require(../models/userSchema)

Comment: So all is working great now, except for the fact that upon a correct username and password,  I keep getting redirected back to my index instead of my dashboard..

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that I can see.

1. You are not importing the usercollectionSchema into the `passport` config and rather the `userRoutes.js` which exports the Router, which most certainly doesn't consists the `findOne()` function.
2. Secondly, you can go ahead and use `require('passport')` in the route file.

I'm just writing out the part which needs to be changed, everything else must be obvious.

In your passport.js file:

```js
const User = require("../models/userModel");
```

In your userRoutes.js file:

```js
const passport = require("passport");
```